# Trigger event on Windows Mobile 6 in C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

How can I trigger a time event on a Windows Mobile 6 app to check my database every five minutes? I'm looking for something like that done in the System.Timers namespace.

Comment: I hope this app is to load on your personal device and no one else will ever run it.  Generally users get very unhappy if you run their battery down with periodic events.

Comment: If the timer is implemented with the underlying OS notifications (like the LIT in my answer), there really is no battery penalty.  It works as a timer interrupt just like calendar reminders do.

Comment: System.Threading.Timer is a *much* better alternative.

Comment: @Hans: Better than what, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the System.Threading.Timer, or the Windows.Forms.Timer.  If neither of those work, [the SDF](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx) has [a LargeIntervalTimer](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2007/03/23/SDF21PreviewGetLIT.aspx) as well as a precision Timer2.